# Fast string hashing function with least chance of collision

Tags: java, hash, hash-function

I have millions of strings, several kilobytes each. I am searching for a fast, collision-free hashing function in Java. Can anybody help me? Is there any such hash function that wasn't made with cryptography in mind, just performance? Any suggestion?

Comment: There is no such thing as a collision-free hashing function for strings. You could build a `Map<String, Integer>` to assign a unique value to each string, but that wouldn't be a hashing function.

Comment: I'm talking about hashing function that won't generate collisions in my case, not about hashing function that's unable to generate collisions.

Comment: Yes, using a map to assign unique value to each string will generate a collision-free value, for a particular set of strings.

Comment: I'd rather use one of cryptographic hash functions

Comment: Ok, then do so, but no matter which cryptographic algorithm you use, it cannot guarantee a collision-free hash.

Comment: I know, but the chance of collisions in that case is dismissively small.

Comment: Why do you need to hash these strings?

Comment: If you don't need any of the security properties of a cryptographic hash then any of the [non-cryptographic hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions#Non-cryptographic_hash_functions) that are 128 bits or more should be adequate and much, much faster. Just one example is [this](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-eastlake-fnv-17#section-6.1.3).

Answer (score 0):

You use this as the key

```
static class Key {

    private static final int R = 256;
    private static final long Q = longRandomPrime();

    private String k;

    public Key(String k) {
      this.k = k;
    }

    public String key() {
      return k;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return Long.hashCode(hash());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o)
        return true;
      if (o == null)
        return false;
      if (getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;
      Key other = (Key) o;
      return k.equals(other.k);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return k;
    }

    private long hash() {
      long h = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < k.length(); j++) {
        h = (R * h + k.charAt(j)) % Q;
      }
      return h;
    }

    private static long longRandomPrime() {
      BigInteger prime = BigInteger.probablePrime(31, new Random());
      return prime.longValue();
    }
  }
```

Comment: It generates 64-bit hash, which is too short.

Comment: @MikhailYevchenko: Didn't you said that you have only *millions* of Strings? A 64 bit hash would allow a multitude more values than you need.

Comment: 64-bit hash has about 0.1% chance of collision for 200m hashes.